# Magento 2 Migration Error customer_eav_attribute and index_process_event

Tags: magento2, data-migration

I am getting error during migration from Magento 1.9.3.1 to Magento 2.2.4.

```
[2018-01-09 09:01:32][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_CSTR_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 185,186,187 from `customer_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`
```

and

```
[2018-01-09 09:01:32][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT_EVENT_ID_INDEX_EVENT_EVENT_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 36788 from `index_process_event`.`event_id` has no referenced records in `index_event`
```

Can you guys help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by going to file

/var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/

class-map.xml

and add line in the end of file.

```
<rename><from>Amasty_Customerattr_Model_Rewrite_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default</from>
        <to></to>
    </rename>
```

while in "Amasty_Customerattr_Model_Rewrite_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default" (this is only example,in your case it will different for different attributes)is the frontend_model in table "eav_attribute".

You can add frontend_model for all attribute id "185,186,187" in same class-map.xml file.

This will ignore your attributes "185,186,187" and will continue your migration.

Comment: Why downvote my answer,let me know reason?